# Does a docker container when paused have similar proprieties of a VM when snapshoted?

Tags: docker, containers, virtual-machine

More specifically, if the memory of a docker container is preserved the same way a snapshoted VM is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the same. The typical definition of a VM snapshot is the filesystem at a point in time.

The container pause command freezes the process, but the processes still exist in memory. This is not gathering a point in time to revert to, but rather a way to control an application running inside of a container. Originally this was just a SIGSTOP sent to each process but has since been changed to use a cgroup freezer setting that cannot be detected or trapped by the container. See the docs on the pause command here:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pause/

If you're looking more for a live migration type of functionality, there have been some projects to do this, but that does not exist directly in docker at this time.